# PHP- Sort Indexed array according to the values of another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Basically,I want to sort an array based on another array.

As in,

```
<?php
$movies=array("Avengers","Spiderman","Batman","Flash");
$ratings=array(9,3,4,7,);
?>
```

In other words,the `$movies[0]`("Avengers") has a ratings of `9` , `$movies[1]`("Spiderman") has a rating of  `3` and so on.

I want the ratings array to be sorted numerically in descending order and thus sorting the movies array.I will like this to be in a function.
 Thus, the array will be thus:

```
<?php
$movies=array("Spiderman","Batman","Flash","Avengers",);
$ratings=array(3,4,7,9);
?>
```

The `ratings` array has been sorted and thus the `movies` array has also been sorted but according to the `ratings` array.

I am sorry I am a newbie in php and I know that doing that is probably very simple but I don't know how to do It.The only way I can think of is using inserting into an sql table then selecting from it in descending order but that will probably be a very bad idea.....

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Oh and if it is easier to do it in Laravel (I use laravel) please show me how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to combine movie names and ratings.

So, that movie names will be the keys of resulting array and ratings will be the values.

Now, sort using [arsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) so that the new array will be sorted in descending order by ratings keeping movie names as it is.

Print the array.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$movies=array("Spiderman","Batman","Flash","Avengers",);
$ratings=array(3,4,7,9);
$movieRatings = array_combine($movies, $ratings);
arsort($movieRatings);
echo '<pre>';print_r($movieRatings);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Avengers] => 9
    [Flash] => 7
    [Batman] => 4
    [Spiderman] => 3
)
```

Comment: Thanks.But how do I get a a  value?

Comment: And I said that I need it in descending order

Comment: U deleted my comment :-(

Comment: @Titoxdboss, did not get the point: You deleted my comment. I haven't deleted anything. Please let me know I am missing something.

Comment: @Titoxdboss, I have already upvoted on the day question was posted.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
array_combine ( array $keys , array $values ) : array
```

it works by setting the values in one array as keys of another array which in your case is your movies.

```
<?php
$movies=array("Avengers","Spiderman","Batman","Flash");
$ratings=array(9,3,4,7,);

$result = array_combine ( $movies, $ratings);

// then sort this way...

arsort($result, 0);
?>
```

documentation for both functions are here...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_arsort.asp

Comment: i just updated for descending order...it arsort()...the result is an array so you would access it like an array as $result[$index]...i.e. $result[0] would give avengers.

Comment: Can u pls upvote my question.....I've been banned from asking questions